# linkedinj get old network updates

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using linkedinj. I want to get `all the old updates of my first level connections`. I tried to set the date but it displays only the recent only

```
        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("05/18/05");
        Date endDate = new Date();

        network = client.getUserUpdates(userId, networkUpdateTypeSet,startDate,endDate);
```

It shows very recent only. How do i fetch all the updates of a user?

Answer (score 0):

From LinkedIn's [API doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api), a maximum of 250 records can be returned in a single query for network updates. So you cannot get all the old network updates in a single query if there are more than 250 updates. So you may need to issue a number of requests to get all the old updates, for example, updates of one month at a time.